# How to achieve scheduling of a very frequent task on Android?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to send via the UDP protocol one single datagram at a fixed rate, every 30ms or so. I managed to do that with ease using three classes, `Timer`, `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and `Handler`.

All three approaches had the same issue, everything works well, then suddendly a sender thread freezes for a few seconds, then datagrams are send quicker than they should (every 10-15ms) and then everything goes back to normal, for about a minute, then the whole process starts again.

I'm not really sure how should I fix it, is it a GC that makes my thread hang? Or maybe there is nothing I can do here and I should implement some kind of buffer on a receiving device?

**EDIT:**

After a few days of trying a number of different solutions, I've managed to solve my problem, but in a very peculiar way. The trick was to send datagrams at a fixed rate of 10ms, so much more frequently than I need. I'm not really sure why it works, but it does, I tested this solution on three different routers and as many phones I had access to. This is not a perfect way of solving my problem and I'd love to know a better way to do so, but for now it will do.

Comment: This kind of application loos like a Real Time System. And to build one of those, you need to begin with a platform that supports Real Time processes (they are quite specialized).

Comment: Do you have any code? what classes di you use? Did you use DatagramSocket?

Comment: I have a lot of code, but almost all is irrelevan to my problem and works well. And yes, I am using DatagramSocket. The receiving device has a rather small CPU and a limited memory, so I'd rather not implement a buffer on it, but at this point I'm not sure I have any other choice than try this solution.

Comment: @Paputek instead of editing your question you should post your solution as answer and then simply accept your own answer to close the question